# how can call method of class in the if statement?

Tags: python

```
choice= input("Enter your choice")

if choice== 1:
        print("Add Student")

        student_id= int(input("Enter the students ID"))
        student_name= raw_input("Enter the students Name")
        student_standard= raw_input("Enter the students standard")
        Stud().stud(student_id,student_name,student_standard)

        print("Added Successfully")

else:
    print "Invalid Choice"


class Stud:

    def stud(self,student_id,student_name,student_standard):

        self.student_id=student_id
        self.student_name=student_name
        self.student_standard=student_standard

        return "Student's id=",self.student_id
        return "Student's name=",self.student_name
        return "student's standard=",self.student_standard
```

Comment: What is your problem with your current code?

Comment: You call the method correctly. The problem is with the class: you should separate the setup code into `__init__`, and you can only `return` once from a given function call.

Comment: Did you mean `print` instead of `return` in your function?

Comment: `input` returns a string and so `choice` will never be `1` but `"1"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several issues. To make your code run, you should fix at least the following issues:

- Move class Stud to the top - you should not call a method before its definition
- Call method stud through Stud object - that means you should first create an object of Stud class.

Following is the working version of your code:

```
choice= input("Enter your choice")
class Stud:

    def stud(self,student_id,student_name,student_standard):

        self.student_id=student_id
        self.student_name=student_name
        self.student_standard=student_standard

        return "Student's id=",self.student_id
        return "Student's name=",self.student_name
        return "student's standard=",self.student_standard

if choice== 1:
        print("Add Student")

        student_id= int(input("Enter the students ID"))
        student_name= raw_input("Enter the students Name")
        student_standard= raw_input("Enter the students standard")
        stud = Stud()
        stud.stud(student_id,student_name,student_standard)

        print("Added Successfully")

else:
    print "Invalid Choice"
```